# vb.net graph not showing all labels

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have to draw a graph and I am using following commands for drawing it in visual studio form (R2 is graph name):

R2.Series(0).Points.AddXY("Wire interchanged", Wire_interchanged)

R2.Series(0).Points.AddXY("Loose connections", Loose_connections)

R2.Series(0).Points.AddXY("Wire is missing", Wire_missing)

R2.Series(0).Points.AddXY("Wrong assembly", Wrong_assembly)

R2.Series(0).Points.AddXY("Stickers/ferrule missing", Stickers_ferrule_missing)

R2.Series(0).Points.AddXY("Earthing straps/earthing not done", Earthing)

R2.Series(0).Points.AddXY("Component rating not matching", Component_rating)

R2.Series(0).Points.AddXY("Drawing is not updated", Drawing_not_updated)

R2.Series(0).Points.AddXY("Human error", Human_error)

R2.Series(0).Points.AddXY("Mechanical problem", Mechanical_problem)

R2.Series(0).Points.AddXY("Other", Other)

All Y coordinates are integers and X coordinates are names. What I observed is, it does not display all lables when I draw more than 8 points. As example, below is graph with 9 points (I commented R2.Series(0).Points.AddXY("Mechanical problem", Mechanical_problem) and  R2.Series(0).Points.AddXY("Other", Other))

[image]

Below is the graph with all 11 points (only alternate labels are displayed)

[image]

A help would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting [Axis.Interval Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.interval?view=netframework-4.8.1) to make the label appear.

```
    R2.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1
```